# Redux saga Infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I haven't been using Redux Saga for very long but I have been stuck on this problem and I can't get my head around it, even after reading other posts related to mine.  Redux saga is entering an infinite loop.

app.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "GAMES_FETCH_REQUESTED" });
  }, []);
```

useGetGames.ts

```
export const useGetGames = (today: string, pastDate: string) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`${BASE_URL}games?key=${API_KEY}&dates=${pastDate},${today}&ordering=-metacritic`).then(res => {
            const data = res.data
            return data
        })
    }, [])
}
```

store.ts

```
function* getNewAndTrendingAction() {
    const games: rawgAPIType = yield call(useGetGames, todayLocal, sixMonthsAgoLocal )
    yield put({ type: 'GAMES_FETCH_SUCCEEDED', payload: games })
    
}
function* getTopGamesAction() {
    const topGames: rawgAPIType = yield call(topAllTimeGames)
    yield put({ type: 'TOP_GAMES_FETCH_SUCCEEDED', payload: topGames })
}

function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery('GAMES_FETCH_REQUESTED', getNewAndTrendingAction)
    yield takeEvery('TOP_GAMES_FETCH_REQUESTED', getTopGamesAction)

}

const initState = {
    games: {},
    topGames: {}
}

const reducer = (
    state: any = initState,
    action: { type: string; payload: rawgAPIType }
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GAMES_FETCH_SUCCEEDED':
            return {...state, 
                games: action.payload}
        case 'TOP_GAMES_FETCH_SUCCEEDED':
            return {...state,
                topGames: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: [sagaMiddleware]
})

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

interface StateProps {
    games: rawgAPIType,
    topGames: rawgAPIType
}
export const selectGames = (state: StateProps) => state.games
export const selectTopGames = (state: StateProps) => state.topGames
```

I have my redux stuff in a single file for now.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't my saga in the end, it was a rogue useEffect